# How can a user upload a résumé in Word or other common format and have it uploaded into my DB in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, upload

How does résumé upload work? I have a site in PHP and right now users can build their résumé line by line, because it is stored in db table. How can a user upload a resume in Word or other common format and have it uploaded into my db? Is it something to do with regex? Are there any scripts out there available that can do that?

Just trying to understand the process.

Thanks.

---

UPDATE:

BTW I looked around a bit and saw web-forms for resume creation -- I already have that. I need a user to be able to point webform to his/er resume, click SUBMIT and have that document input into db automagically.

Comment: I francophonized the spelling of résumé so that it doesn't get mixed up with resuming an upload.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resume

Comment: Uploading is a generic process. What did you try? Did you read the documentation on uploading? You'll do better here if you 1. make an effort to build the thing you want. 2. Ask a specific question about it.

Comment: In another word, how to parse a .doc document with PHP? Is that it?

Comment: Sorry, my question was a bit too broad. No, I know how to upload file... I was trying to figure out what happens or should happen next, in general. Is there a collection of regex formulas that match certain patters and extract the parts that match portions on the document that match db table fields to input? Or is there anyhting else that is used besides regex? What file formats are to start with? I assume it is easier with with .TXT but I'm afraid not many used that for resume formatting. So is it RTF? Once I can wrap my ming around this I can start writing code.

Comment: I think he's talking about parsing the résumé after upload to try to get it into a database.  The input must be constrained somehow or you are not going to be able to parse it into fields use by the database.

Comment: Yes, I am mainly wondering how to get the text off the résumé and parse it into the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the file uploading feature:

1. create a HTML page containing a `<form>` and a file input.
2. create a PHP script that receives the uploaded file

The process is simple: user selects a file to upload and the browser sends it to a PHP script designated by the **`action`** attribute of the `<form>` tag. After the file is uploaded into the server, you can do whatever you want with it.

[PHP file upload tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)

[File uploading guidelines in PHP manual](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: he's talking about uploading a document. Not resuming an upload.

Comment: it's about version control I think?

Comment: @Cfreak: Yup. The initial wording of the title was a bit misleading.